# Transmission WebUI 409 in Docker Container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, transmission-daemon

So, I've set up a docker container on my server host to act as a transmission-daemon seedbox. I installed openssh and transmission-daemon on the official Ubuntu 14.04 container. I forwarded port 9091 on the container to the host so I could access the container remotely, and I set up transmission-daemon with the following settings.json file:

```
{
    "alt-speed-down": 50,
    "alt-speed-enabled": false,
    "alt-speed-time-begin": 540,
    "alt-speed-time-day": 127,
    "alt-speed-time-enabled": false,
    "alt-speed-time-end": 1020,
    "alt-speed-up": 50,
    "bind-address-ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
    "bind-address-ipv6": "::",
    "blocklist-enabled": false,
    "blocklist-url": "http://www.example.com/blocklist",
    "cache-size-mb": 4,
    "dht-enabled": true,
    "download-dir": "/root/transmission/complete",
    "download-limit": 100,
    "download-limit-enabled": 0,
    "download-queue-enabled": true,
    "download-queue-size": 5,
    "encryption": 1,
    "idle-seeding-limit": 30,
    "idle-seeding-limit-enabled": false,
    "incomplete-dir": "/root/transmission/incomplete",
    "incomplete-dir-enabled": true,
    "lpd-enabled": false,
    "max-peers-global": 200,
    "message-level": 2,
    "peer-congestion-algorithm": "",
    "peer-id-ttl-hours": 6,
    "peer-limit-global": 200,
    "peer-limit-per-torrent": 50,
    "peer-port": 51413,
    "peer-port-random-high": 65535,
    "peer-port-random-low": 49152,
    "peer-port-random-on-start": false,
    "peer-socket-tos": "default",
    "pex-enabled": true,
    "port-forwarding-enabled": false,
    "preallocation": 1,
    "prefetch-enabled": 1,
    "queue-stalled-enabled": true,
    "queue-stalled-minutes": 30,
    "ratio-limit": 2,
    "ratio-limit-enabled": false,
    "rename-partial-files": true,
    "rpc-authentication-required": true,
    "rpc-bind-address": "0.0.0.0",
    "rpc-enabled": true,
    "rpc-password": "{0477ada0ba97374d44fc4e78a5328dc32107ed26yYyN9qwZ",
    "rpc-port": 9091,
    "rpc-url": "/transmission/",
    "rpc-username": "transmission",
    "rpc-whitelist": "*.*.*.*",
    "rpc-whitelist-enabled": false,
    "scrape-paused-torrents-enabled": true,
    "script-torrent-done-enabled": false,
    "script-torrent-done-filename": "",
    "seed-queue-enabled": false,
    "seed-queue-size": 10,
    "speed-limit-down": 100,
    "speed-limit-down-enabled": false,
    "speed-limit-up": 100,
    "speed-limit-up-enabled": false,
    "start-added-torrents": true,
    "trash-original-torrent-files": false,
    "umask": 2,
    "upload-limit": 100,
    "upload-limit-enabled": 0,
    "upload-slots-per-torrent": 14,
    "utp-enabled": true
}
```

Whenever I connect to the server via http://ip_addr:9091/transmission/web/ or http://ip_addr:9091/transmission/ I get the following error:

> 409: Conflict
>
> Your request had an invalid session-id header.
>
> To fix this, follow these steps:
>
> When reading a response, get its X-Transmission-Session-Id header and
>   remember it Add the updated header to your outgoing requests When you
>   get this 409 error message, resend your request with the updated
>   header This requirement has been added to help prevent CSRF attacks.
>
> X-Transmission-Session-Id:
>   ulkx30bOoRTIw1yu4s0GCvUAGY6VFY844Iag3f8sfYtZjbRm

Any ideas what I can do to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem like it, but just to rule out the possibility; are you using Apache or Nginx as a proxy to your docker container? You might also need to make sure you go to `http://ip_addr:9091` in your web browser first to acquire the header. `http://ip_addr:9091/transmission/` may expect that header to be set already.

Comment: I wasn't running a proxy, but I just restarted the server and cleared my cache and everything started running, haha. I think you need to clear your cookies so that the new session id is granted. I also turned off rpc-authentication in the settings, so that could also have fixed it.